Podman Desktop registries error "Wrong Username or Password." during login
I am trying Podman Desktop 1.10.3 app for the first time.
I assume that in order to locate pre-made images such as for Postgres or MySQL database servers, I must first provide username & password to one or more registries.
In the Podman Desktop > Settings > Registries panel, I was able to successfully enter a username and password for Red Hat Quay. Unfortunately, I cannot find any images there.
When I enter my Docker.com username & password credentials for the Docker Hub item listed in that panel, I get this error:

Wrong Username or Password.

When I enter my Google account username & password for the Google Container Registry item, I get the same error:

Wrong Username or Password.

Is there same trick to making a login to those Registries items?
